# Unique filter condition

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a rather complex goal in mind, but in short, I'm trying to make a filter on a range that would only leave unique names which have a condition "Add" and not "Remove". Problem is, the data will be continuously populated via form submission and some names will be removed and re-added down the road, so if same name is encountered in the range and has both one "Add" and one "Remove"(or equal amount of add and remove) - it shouldn't show up in filtered data. Please see the spreadsheet below for example.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18n7b6hEh9X3A14-PCQSwOPQr8nTin2X9-NBKmPSv48Q/edit#gid=0

Alternatively i was thinking of collecting the latest encounter of the unique name. So if the same name is encountered multiple times - retrieve the entry which is closest to today and only show it if condition matches "Add". This solution would be more beneficial but seem to be harder to achieve.

Either solution would help a lot. Appreciate your insight.

Comment: I proposed to change [tag:excel-formula] by [tag:formulas] as the first is specific for Excel formulas that the asker already wrote but the question doesn't include any formula besides that it's about [tag:google-spreadsheet] not [tag:excel], while the last ([tag:formulas]) is a generic tag for spreadsheet formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 =unique(query(arrayformula(iferror(if(isodd(COUNTIF(C2:C8,C2:C8)),C2:C8,""))),   "select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc", 0 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

may be use double query:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:C11,"select C, count(A) where B <> '' group by C pivot B"),"select Col1 where Col3 is null")
```

also this formula could work:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C10,ArrayFormula(MMULT(--(C2:C10=TRANSPOSE(C2:C10)),--(B2:B10="Remove")))=0))
```